# Why does this "wlog" make sense: $L^p$-norms of random variables

Tags: random-variables, normed-spaces, martingales

Let $$\overline{X_n}:=\max_{0 \leq m \leq n} X_m^+$$ for a sequence of random variables $X_i, i \geq 1$ (in fact, it is a submartingale),

where $X_m^+:=\max(X_m,0)$.

We want to show that $$||\overline{X_n}||_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} ||X_n||_p.$$

To do so, our first step is to state that we can assume wlog that $X_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, otherwise we would just replace $X_n$ by $X_n^+$.

So what this means is that we need to show that if it holds for $X_n^+$, then it holds for $X_n$ as well, right? So why does $$||\overline{X_n^+}||_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} ||X_n^+||_p$$ imply $$||\overline{X_n}||_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} ||X_n||_p?$$

**What I thought of:**

$$||\overline{X_n}||_p = ||\overline{X_n^+}||_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} ||X_n^+||_p.$$

But I do not get how I can conculde $$||X_n^+||_p \leq ||X_n||_p.$$

Is my idea completely wrong? Can you help me why we can assume non-negativity wlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$|X_n| \geq \max\{X_n,0\} = X_n^+ = |X_n^+|$$ implies $$\int |X_n|^p \, d\mathbb{P} \geq \int |X_n^+|^p \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for any $p \geq 1$. Hence, $$\|X_n\|_p \geq \|X_n^+\|_p.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. Quite obvious, now when I see your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user136457 You are welcome.